# phoenix view issue on top of hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop2, apache-phoenix

I am using Hbase version 2.0.2 and phoenix V5.0.0. I have an HBase table on top of that We have created Phoenix view, using the below steps

```
hbase(main):007:0> create 'phownix_test','details'
    hbase(main):008:0> put 'phownix_test','1','details:MAC','1234567'
    Took 1.5056 seconds
    hbase(main):009:0> put 'phownix_test','1','details:deviceName','RAINDEVICE'
    Took 0.0101 seconds
    hbase(main):010:0> put 'phownix_test','1','details:CO2','234.543'
    Took 0.0079 seconds
    hbase(main):011:0> put 'phownix_test','1','details:latitude','9876543'
    Took 0.0084 seconds
    hbase(main):012:0> scan 'phownix_test'
    ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL
     1                                          column=details:CO2, timestamp=1609744038606, value=234.543
     1                                          column=details:MAC, timestamp=1609744024895, value=1234567
     1                                          column=details:deviceName, timestamp=1609744031974, value=RAINDEVICE
     1                                          column=details:latitude, timestamp=1609744051328, value=9876543
```

then I have created a phoenix view on top of the HBase table.

```
create view "phownix_test"("ID" VARCHAR primary key,"details"."MAC" UNSIGNED_INT,"details"."CO2" UNSIGNED_FLOAT,"details"."deviceName" VARCHAR,"details"."latitude" UNSIGNED_LONG);
```

while selecting data from phoenix view I am getting below error.

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:> select * from "phownix_test";

Error: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. Expected length of at least 51 bytes, but had 23 (state=22000,code=201)
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. Expected length of at least 51 bytes, but had 23
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:503)
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:150)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.KeyValueSchema.next(KeyValueSchema.java:214)
        at org.apache.phoenix.expression.ProjectedColumnExpression.evaluate(ProjectedColumnExpression.java:116)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ExpressionProjector.getValue(ExpressionProjector.java:69)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixResultSet.getString(PhoenixResultSet.java:635)
        at sqlline.Rows$Row.<init>(Rows.java:183)
        at sqlline.BufferedRows.<init>(BufferedRows.java:38)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.print(SqlLine.java:1660)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:833)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:813)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:686)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:291)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding a Phoenix view to an existing HBase table, you must ensure the values stored in the table are encoded into bytes the way Phoenix expects them to be.  Since you wrote data into the table from the HBase shell instead of through Phoenix this might not have happened (your error message suggests that is the case).

If it's a new table, don't use the HBase shell -- instead use Phoenix SQL commands to create the table. That way everything will be configured the way Phoenix expects.  Then henceforth use only Phoenix to interact with the data (write, query, create views, and so on) to avoid problems associated with different encodings and the like.

Comment: I am able to Map with Phoenix view with particular datatypes also now. but Here My Doubt is I have enabled Snappy compression for the HBase table. Is there any possible Things to improve performance Other than the Row key and compression technique, If I want to read data from phoenix view?

Answer (score 0):

The Moment we Inserting into Hbase only We have to Encode the data in Binary format. Then We can create Phoenix View with required Datatypes accordingly. It Worked For me